# MS Access accepts a query but pyodbc doesn't

Tags: database, ms-access, pyodbc

I currently have an MS Access file that is about 1GB in size. I run an SQL query inside of it, with a bunch of joins, in order to obtain the exact data that i need for my reports. That bit works just fine, despite being quite slow.

In an effort to diminish the time it takes to perform these tasks, i am trying to do this very same thing using the PYODBC library, in Python. I have been able to connect to the MS Access file just fine, i can view all the tables and the queries that i have, but that exact same query is unable to run while using PYODBC because it "exceeds the maximum file size of 2GB". I have no idea why this happens when connecting to the database via Python but not in Access itself.

The code i am using is this:

```
import pyodbc

pyodbc.drivers()

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Desktop\filename.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for i in cursor.tables():
    print(i)

autocommit=True # i read this shrinks the temp file size, but have tried 'False' as well without success

sql = "{CALL QUERY_NAME}" # the query that runs just fine in MSAccess
cursor.execute(sql)
```

The error message i receive is 'Size of the query result in larger than the maximum size of a database (2GB), or there is not enough temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result'.

Shouldn't this work just as it does inside MSAccess itself? Anyone has any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like your AccessDB is bumping up against its 2gb max limit. You may have some luck opening this access db in Access and using the "Compact and Repair DB" option and rerunning your pyodbc. In my experience though, once you start bumping into that error, it's time to migrate to a real database.

Comment: Wouldn't this error pop up inside of MS Access as well? In the application, it works just fine.

Comment: When you run the query in Access does it open the result in Datasheet View (normal Select query) or does it create/refresh a table?

Comment: It creates a View, which is exactly what i am trying to replicate in Python but am unable to do so. Its a SELECT query, not INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: You might try this: Create a new database called "test.accdb". Create table links in test.accdb that point to the tables in filename.accdb. Import the query from filename.accdb into test.accdb. Have pyodbc connect to test.accdb and run the query from there.

Comment: Hum, if this is just a select, I don't see why the 2gig limit would come into play. And this: n an effort to diminish the time it takes to perform these tasks, i am trying to do this very same thing using the PYODBC library, in Python. --- no, you not going to get ANY more performance by using c++, c# .net, or VBA and Access. You still using the SAME data engine code - and that data engine code does not out of the blue decide to run faster if you hit Access data with c++, hand coded assembly language, or say Python.  You not really processing limited here - but are data rate pull limted.

Comment: Makes sense, Albert. That's a bummer, then. Thank you all for replying anyway!